# Query with Array parameter in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: rest, couchdb, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm looking to build a query using an array as parameter, something like this:

Model File

```
asset Car identified by id {
    o String id
    --> Model model
}
asset Model identifierd by id {
    o String id
    o String name
}
```

Query to retrieve all the cars with specified models:

```
query getCarsByModels {
    statement:
        SELECT ie.example.Car
            WHERE (_$modelArray CONTAINS model)
}
```

Querying the endpoint I receive this error: `undefined is a required argument`, which apparently it’s the same error raised (and solved) in this issue: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/2539.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: hi, could you post your model file please and also specify what version of Composer you are using - thanks.  Issue 2539 was fixed by Pull request https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/pull/2728

Comment: Edited with model. I am using version v0.19.8

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems with the definition you supplied:

1) Your model file should say as follows (perhaps a cut-n-paste error?)

```
asset Model identified by id {
    o String id
    o String name
}
```

2) The operation `CONTAINS` should be used against an Array field. Your asset definition (for `Car`) does not have a field that is an array.

3) Your Query needs to have the operands the right way around: - your 'left-hand' field has to be that which is defined in your model somewhere -ie  the actual array field eg.

```
query getCarsByModels {
    statement:
        SELECT ie.example.Car
            WHERE ( model CONTAINS _$model )
}
```

and where your model would be

```
asset Car identified by id {
    o String id
    --> Model[] model    // or `o Model[] model`
}
```

I have to ask - why do you need an array - when you could simply just do:

```
query getCarsByModels {
    statement:
        SELECT ie.example.Car
            WHERE ( model == _$model )
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul for your comment. I agree with your points but I should probably explain better why I actually need an array as parameter.

Assuming the model I posted above, with a Model for each Car.
As of now I am using a simple query to get cars for a specific model, and it works fine:

query getCarsByModels {
    SELECT ie.example.Car
    WHERE (model == _$model)
}

My issue comes when I have multiple models to check, as I have to make one call for each model, and I may have 100+ models to check.

As workaround I'm using Loopback filters, but a query will be more clean.

Comment: sure, if you're search Cars with `Model[]` defined as an array of relationships (as above) stored in the `Car` asset, you would search on the model ids you require using `CONTAINS` - but with the fully-qualified relationship identifier. This can be created in a function them supplied to the query.  Otherwise you have to use the Loopback filter route as you wrote.

Comment: Hi Paul, let me see if I can explain the use-case my colleague Nicola intends. Currently we have a "Car" asset with a certain "model", and we want to be able to get all the assets that correspond to either model A, B or C. Each car has only one model, so an array does not seem to make sense to us in the asset itself

Comment: In summary, we want to be able to do something like this:

Comment: ```model ==_$modelA OR model ==_$modelA OR ...```

Comment: But not just with 2 or 3 models, but an arbitrary number of models

Comment: In which case,  I'm not sure a query may your best fit - you have an arbitrary number of models to search the Car asset for. Where does, the 'INPUT' arbitrary number of models come from - a client app ? Just thinking you could run a query to get all Cars , or range of Cars at a time (reduce load) then use javascript in a transaction function (that only calls the query) - to check/process the array of results to see if a Car model found, is a match in your arraycheck `arbitraryArray.find(resultArray[n].model.getIdentifier())  ; ` // processing one result, within a query results array pls note

Comment: `.find()` immediately returns the value of that element when found. Or use the `.some()` method. The some() method executes the function once for each element present in the array: If it finds an array element that matches the function (ie a model in this case) returns a true value (and does not check the remaining values in the array, so you can go onto the next model id etc in your arbitrary list). This is all done in-memory.